# Arch linux, set up user to use pacman without full root privileges

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, users, root, pacman

I am trying to set up multiple levels of users on my arch linux system. I want to lock the root user, and then have 3 levels of user. On top is essentially is a full wheel root user, then under that I want a less privileged user that do some high level functions like using pacman. So I have not added the submasteruser to the wheel group
I have used visudo and added the following lines

```
User_Alias    SUBMASTER = submasteruser
Cmnd_Alias    SUBMASTER = /usr/bin/pacman
SUBMASTER ALL=(ALL) SUBMASTER
```

but still when I try to user sudo pacman -Syu or sudo pacman -S git etc
I get an error: sorry submasteruser is not allowed to execute /usr/bin/pacman

is there some other files I need to include in my /etc/sudoers Cmnd_Alias for SUBMASTER? Or am I missing some basic info here?

Comment: Have you tried to put `submasteruser` in a group (say, `admins`), and then use `%admins ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/pacman`? Also, I'm not using Arch now, have you tried `whereis pacman`? to avoid a simple `bin` vs `sbin` mistake?

Comment: Keep in mind that `pacman` allows [offline installation from files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/offline_installation_of_packages). If any user can use pacman as root, it can become root as well by installing some arbitrary package on the system.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt realize that pacman can work offline, that makes sense. Also it turns out the problem was that I was including other programs in a list (Cmnd_Alias    SUBMASTER = /usr/bin/pacman /usr/bin/systemctl) etc and I for got to separate them by commas, a very silly mistake

Comment: Ok, try to include all of your scenario the next time. That would be an implicit balance with the examples being minimal.